# Lexer with a parser combinator

Tags: rust, community-challenge, language-design

A follow up to [my previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/174830/100439) which was on the token library that this lexer produces a stream of.

View [the full project](https://github.com/nafi-lang/rust-nafi/tree/38c09837a2573f08144cae7255be3566f5814615), [the tokens library](https://github.com/nafi-lang/rust-nafi/tree/38c09837a2573f08144cae7255be3566f5814615/tokens), [the parser combinator library](https://github.com/nafi-lang/rust-nafi/tree/38c09837a2573f08144cae7255be3566f5814615/nnom), or [this lexer library](https://github.com/nafi-lang/rust-nafi/tree/38c09837a2573f08144cae7255be3566f5814615/lexer) on GitHub (pinned to the relevant commit). [Documentation](https://nafi-lang.github.io/rust-nafi/) is available (built from master) for [nnom](https://nafi-lang.github.io/rust-nafi/nnom/index.html), [tokens](https://nafi-lang.github.io/rust-nafi/nafi_tokens/index.html), and [lexer](https://nafi-lang.github.io/rust-nafi/nafi_lexer/index.html).

This is the lexer for the language I've been working on. Its job is to take a string and parse it into tokens, which will then be piped into later steps of the language processing. As an example use, here is the [REPL I wrote for the lexer](https://github.com/nafi-lang/rust-nafi/tree/master/lexer/repl):

```
extern crate nafi_lexer;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut buffer = String::with_capacity(80);
    loop {
        buffer.clear();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer).expect("IO Failure");
        if buffer.is_empty() {
            break;
        }
        let tokens = nafi_lexer::lex(buffer.trim());
        println!("{:?}", tokens);
    }
}
```

You can run this locally by using `cargo run --package=nafi-lexer` after cloning the repository. It requires nightly rust, as I'm making use of impl Trait and the never type.

### lib.rs

```
//! Transformation of NAFI source code into tokens

#![forbid(bad_style, missing_debug_implementations, unconditional_recursion, future_incompatible)]
#![deny(missing_docs, unsafe_code, unused)]
#![feature(conservative_impl_trait, const_fn, dotdoteq_in_patterns, never_type, option_filter)]

#[macro_use]
extern crate matches;
extern crate nafi_tokens as tokens;
extern crate nnom;
extern crate unic_ucd_category;

use nnom::ParseOutput;
use tokens::Token;

mod lexer;

/// Lex NAFI source into its component tokens
pub fn lex(s: &str) -> Vec<Token> {
    let Ok(ParseOutput { output, .. }) = lexer::tokens(s.into());
    output
}
```

### lexer/mod.rs

```
use nnom::{ParseOutput, ParseResult};
use nnom::combinators::many0;
use nnom::slice::PositionedStr;
use tokens::{Keyword, Symbol, Token};
use unic_ucd_category::GeneralCategory;

mod literals;
mod unicode;
mod whitespace;

use self::literals::{integer_literal, string_literal};
use self::unicode::identifier;
use self::whitespace::whitespace;

pub fn tokens(input: PositionedStr) -> ParseResult<(), Vec<Token>, !> {
    many0(token)(input).map(
        |ParseOutput {
             remaining_input,
             output,
         }| {
            assert!(remaining_input.is_empty());
            ParseOutput {
                remaining_input: (),
                output,
            }
        },
    )
}

fn token(input: PositionedStr) -> ParseResult<PositionedStr, Token, ()> {
    Err(())
        .or_else(|_| whitespace(input))
        .or_else(|_| integer_literal(input))
        .or_else(|_| string_literal(input))
        .or_else(|_| identifier_like(input))
        .or_else(|_| symbol(input))
        .or_else(|_| _unknown(input))
}

/// `Token::Identifier` or `Token::Keyword`
fn identifier_like(input: PositionedStr) -> ParseResult<PositionedStr, Token, ()> {
    identifier(input).map(
        |ParseOutput {
             remaining_input,
             output,
         }| {
            ParseOutput {
                remaining_input,
                output: match &*output {
                    "let" => Token::Keyword(input.start(), Keyword::Let),
                    "mutable" => Token::Keyword(input.start(), Keyword::Mutable),
                    "if" => Token::Keyword(input.start(), Keyword::If),
                    "else" => Token::Keyword(input.start(), Keyword::Else),
                    _ => Token::Identifier(input.start(), (&*output).into()),
                },
            }
        },
    )
}

/// `Token::Symbol`
fn symbol(input: PositionedStr) -> ParseResult<PositionedStr, Token, ()> {
    let ch = input.chars().next().ok_or(())?;
    let category = GeneralCategory::of(ch);
    if category.is_symbol() || category.is_punctuation() {
        Ok(ParseOutput {
            remaining_input: input.split_at(ch.len_utf8()).1,
            output: Token::Symbol(input.start(), Symbol::from(ch)),
        })
    } else {
        Err(())
    }
}

/// `Token::_Unknown`
fn _unknown(input: PositionedStr) -> ParseResult<PositionedStr, Token, ()> {
    let ch = input.chars().next().ok_or(())?;
    Ok(ParseOutput {
        remaining_input: input.split_at(ch.len_utf8()).1,
        output: Token::_Unknown(input.start(), ch),
    })
}
```

### lexer/literals.rs

```
use super::unicode::decimal_number;
use lexer::token;
use nnom::{ParseOutput, ParseResult};
use nnom::slice::PositionedStr;
use std::{char, u32};
use tokens::{StringFragments, Symbol, Token};

/// `Token::Literal(Literal::Integer)`
pub fn integer_literal(input: PositionedStr) -> ParseResult<PositionedStr, Token, ()> {
    decimal_number(input).map(
        |ParseOutput {
             remaining_input,
             output,
         }| {
            ParseOutput {
                remaining_input,
                output: Token::Literal(input.start(), output.into()),
            }
        },
    )
}

// TODO: Break single-character escapes into reusable fn and build character_literal
/// `Token::Literal(Literal::String)`
pub fn string_literal(input: PositionedStr) -> ParseResult<PositionedStr, Token, ()> {
    if !input.starts_with('"') {
        return Err(());
    }

    let mut remaining_input = input.split_at(1).1;
    let mut string = StringFragments::new();

    loop {
        match remaining_input.chars().next() {
            Some('\"') => {
                remaining_input = remaining_input.split_at(1).1;
                break;
            },
            Some('\\') => {
                remaining_input = remaining_input.split_at(1).1;
                match remaining_input.chars().next() {
                    Some(ch) if matches!(ch, '\\' | '\"' | '\'') => {
                        string.push_char(ch);
                        remaining_input = remaining_input.split_at(1).1;
                    },
                    Some('r') => {
                        string.push_char('\r');
                        remaining_input = remaining_input.split_at(1).1;
                    },
                    Some('n') => {
                        string.push_char('\n');
                        remaining_input = remaining_input.split_at(1).1;
                    },
                    Some('t') => {
                        string.push_char('\t');
                        remaining_input = remaining_input.split_at(1).1;
                    },
                    Some('u') => {
                        if remaining_input.starts_with("u{") {
                            if let Some(idx) = remaining_input.find('}') {
                                let codepoint = u32::from_str_radix(&remaining_input[2..idx], 16);
                                if let Ok(Some(ch)) = codepoint.map(char::from_u32) {
                                    string.push_char(ch);
                                } else {
                                    string.push_invalid_escape(&remaining_input[..idx + 1])
                                }
                                remaining_input = remaining_input.split_at(idx).1;
                            } else {
                                string.push_invalid_escape('u'.to_string());
                            }
                        } else {
                            string.push_invalid_escape('u'.to_string());
                        }
                        remaining_input = remaining_input.split_at(1).1;
                    },
                    Some('{') => {
                        remaining_input = remaining_input.split_at(1).1;
                        let mut tokens: Vec<Token> = vec![];
                        let mut depth = 1u32;
                        while let Ok(ParseOutput {
                            remaining_input: tail,
                            output,
                        }) = token(remaining_input)
                        {
                            remaining_input = tail;
                            match output {
                                Token::Symbol(_, Symbol::LeftCurlyBracket) => depth += 1,
                                Token::Symbol(_, Symbol::RightCurlyBracket) => {
                                    depth -= 1;
                                    if depth == 0 {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                },
                                _ => {},
                            }
                            tokens.push(output);
                        }
                        string.push_interpolation(tokens);
                    },
                    Some(s) => string.push_invalid_escape(s.to_string()),
                    None => break,
                }
            },
            Some(_) => {
                let idx = remaining_input
                    .find(|ch| matches!(ch, '\"' | '\\'))
                    .unwrap_or_else(|| remaining_input.len());
                let (uninteresting, rest) = remaining_input.split_at(idx);
                string.push_string(&*uninteresting);
                remaining_input = rest;
            },
            None => break,
        }
    }

    Ok(ParseOutput {
        remaining_input,
        output: Token::Literal(input.start(), string.into()),
    })
}
```

### lexer/unicode.rs

```
use nnom::{ParseOutput, ParseResult};
use nnom::slice::PositionedStr;
use tokens::BigUint;

pub fn is_newline(ch: char) -> bool { matches!(ch as u32, 0xA..=0xD | 0x85 | 0x2028 | 0x2029) }

pub fn white_space(input: PositionedStr) -> ParseResult<PositionedStr, PositionedStr, ()> {
    let idx = input
        .char_indices()
        .filter(|&(_, ch)| !ch.is_whitespace())
        .map(|(idx, _)| idx)
        .next()
        .unwrap_or_else(|| input.len());
    if idx != 0 {
        let (output, remaining_input) = input.split_at(idx);
        Ok(ParseOutput {
            remaining_input,
            output,
        })
    } else {
        Err(())
    }
}

pub fn identifier(input: PositionedStr) -> ParseResult<PositionedStr, PositionedStr, ()> {
    // TODO: Use Unicode UAX31-R1 instead of this simple definition
    let mut chars = input.chars();
    if let Some(ch) = chars.next() {
        if !ch.is_alphabetic() {
            return Err(());
        }
        let idx = chars.take_while(|ch| ch.is_alphanumeric()).count() + 1;
        let (matched, remaining_input) = input.split_at(idx);
        Ok(ParseOutput {
            remaining_input,
            output: matched,
        })
    } else {
        Err(())
    }
}

pub fn decimal_number(input: PositionedStr) -> ParseResult<PositionedStr, BigUint, ()> {
    let idx = input.chars().take_while(|ch| ch.is_digit(10)).count();
    if idx != 0 {
        let (matched, remaining_input) = input.split_at(idx);
        Ok(ParseOutput {
            remaining_input,
            output: matched.parse().unwrap(),
        })
    } else {
        Err(())
    }
}
```

### lexer/whitespace.rs

```
use super::unicode::{is_newline, white_space};
use nnom::{ParseOutput, ParseResult};
use nnom::slice::PositionedStr;
use tokens::Token;

/// `Token::Whitespace`
pub fn whitespace(input: PositionedStr) -> ParseResult<PositionedStr, Token, ()> {
    let mut rest = input;
    while let Ok(ParseOutput {
        remaining_input, ..
    }) = some_whitespace(rest)
    {
        rest = remaining_input;
    }
    if rest.start() != input.start() {
        Ok(ParseOutput {
            remaining_input: rest,
            output: Token::Whitespace(input.start()),
        })
    } else {
        Err(())
    }
}

/// Consume some whitespace.
fn some_whitespace(input: PositionedStr) -> ParseResult<PositionedStr, PositionedStr, ()> {
    Err(())
        .or_else(|_| white_space(input))
        .or_else(|_| line_comment(input))
        .or_else(|_| block_comment(input))
}

/// Parse a line comment
fn line_comment(input: PositionedStr) -> ParseResult<PositionedStr, PositionedStr, ()> {
    if !input.starts_with("//") {
        return Err(());
    }

    let idx = input.find(is_newline).unwrap_or_else(|| input.len());
    let (output, remaining_input) = input.split_at(idx);
    Ok(ParseOutput {
        remaining_input,
        output,
    })
}

/// Parse a block comment
fn block_comment(input: PositionedStr) -> ParseResult<PositionedStr, PositionedStr, ()> {
    if !input.starts_with("/*") {
        return Err(());
    }

    let mut idx: usize = 2;
    let mut depth = 1;

    while depth > 0 && idx < input.len() {
        let remaining_input = &input[idx..];
        if remaining_input.starts_with("/*") {
            depth += 1;
            idx += 2;
        } else if remaining_input.starts_with("*/") {
            depth -= 1;
            idx += 2;
        } else {
            idx += remaining_input.chars().next().unwrap().len_utf8();
        }
    }

    let (output, remaining_input) = input.split_at(idx);
    Ok(ParseOutput {
        remaining_input,
        output,
    })
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn block_comment() {
        assert_eq!(
            super::block_comment("/** /* */*/".into()),
            Ok(ParseOutput {
                output: "/** /* */*/".into(),
                remaining_input: PositionedStr::new("", 11),
            })
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn line_comment() {
        assert_eq!(
            super::line_comment("// any amount of text you want".into()),
            Ok(ParseOutput {
                output: "// any amount of text you want".into(),
                remaining_input: PositionedStr::new("", 30),
            })
        );
    }
}
```

This is a lot of code, so let me guide you to the most interesting parts that would most appreciate review:

- `nafi_lexer::lexer::whitespace::{whitespace, some_whitespace, line_comment, block_comment`

  - Complicated enough I wrote tests for them (though I should definitely have more)
- `nafi_lexer::lexer::literals::string_literal`

  - Most complicated parser fragment. Since I want string interpolation like `"1 + 1 = \{1+1}"` to work in my language, the lexer has to be recursive here. I definitely need some more tests here for more interesting cases like `"\{"}"}"` which used to break it.
- Overall design. I've attempted to create a system built off of [parser combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_combinator). My library `nnom` is inspired by [`nom`](https://crates.io/crates/nom) and [`synom`](https://crates.io/crates/synom), but minimal and without macros.

  - This also means I'm free to change the framework easily, so imports from nnom are fair game for comments.